# Multiple pipes in Powershell

Tags: powershell

How can I process multiple commands on the same item; take this example where I want to display *both* the filename and the last write date but only the filename appears:

```
PS C:\Users\demo> ls *.zip | % { Write-Host $_.FullName }  | % { Write-Host $_.LastTimeWrite }
C:\Users\demo\archive.zip
```

Comment: `ls *.zip | select FullName, LastWritetime`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

first, the `FileInfo` property is called `LastWriteTime` - not `LastTimeWrite`.

You could use a **format string**, like:

```
ls *.zip | % { Write-Host ("{0} {1}" -f $_.FullName, $_.LastWriteTime) }
```

Or you use a **semicolon** to separate the commands:

```
ls *.zip | % { Write-Host $_.FullName; Write-Host $_.LastWriteTime }
```

In case of Write-Host, you can also write

```
ls *.zip | % { Write-Host $_.FullName $_.LastWriteTime }
```

The reason why your pipeline doesn't work as you expect is two-fold:

- `Write-Host` writes output to the host environment (i.e. the console), so there's nothing left to go into the next pipeline step. Use `Write-Output` or `Select-Object` instead of `Write-Host` if you need to further process the results.
- Even if you didn't write the output to the host environment, the next step in the pipeline wouldn't have the same in put as the current step, because you're transforming the `FileInfo` objects into strings in the current step.

Comment: This solves this particular case. I'm actually quite interested in a more general answer on how to have some command output directed via a PowerShell pipeline to two (or more) separate commands (if none supports `-PassThru`). I'm not talking about solutions like `cmd1 | % { cmd2 $_; cmd3 $_ }`, where each pipeline object is processed separately by two command calls, as those commands are - in such case - not processing a pipeline, but a single object, which may have completely different results (e.g. a separate call to `Export-CSV` for each object would not make sense).